# Is there a maximum number of partitions limitation for DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

When searching answer for this question, I ran into this page https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-faq/dynamodb-maximum-number-of-partitions/ saying that

> The maximum number of partitions per table is determined by the total provisioned throughput for the table, with a maximum of 3,000 partitions per table or a maximum of 10 GB per partition.

Is there really such a limitation?

I cannot find any mentioning about this limitation from DynamoDB's [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ServiceQuotas.html). So I am not sure the accuracy of this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB allows virtually unlimited scale. There's no "ouch, ran out of partitions" line. Just nonsense.

There's some deep dive coverage on partition behaviors at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/part-1-scaling-dynamodb-how-partitions-hot-keys-and-split-for-heat-impact-performance/

Comment: Thanks, that's what I would expect too.

Answer (score -1):

The partitioning scheme of DynamoDB is more of an implementation detail that AWS handles automatically based on the provisioned or on-demand capacity mode you choose.

But for more clarity regarding this you should talk to the AWS Support